# How to display Fibonacci numbers using a Linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, integer

I have created a class using linked list to display 20 Fibonacci numbers. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class FibonacciLinkList {
    private LinkedList<Integer> fibonacciList;

    public FibonacciLinkList(LinkedList<Integer> FibonacciLinkList) {
        this.fibonacciList = FibonacciLinkList;
    }

    public LinkedList<Integer> sum()
    {
        int n, a = 0, b = 0, c = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = a + b;
        }
        return fibonacciList;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(fibonacciList);  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList fibonacciList = new LinkedList();
        fibonacciList.display();  //This is where the error is
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is displaying the Fibonacci numbers on the console.

I have tried to do this by using a display method but it hasn't really worked for me. I have done a lot of searching online and on SO and have tried them but they have not worked for me. It would be appreciated if you could fix my code so that it does work.

I am new to linked list and this is the first time I am coding a linked list myself and I feel that a solution to this problem will help me understand linked lists better.

Comment: Hint: your loop in `sum` doesn't actually *do* anything. You start with local variables with particular values, and you modify those local variables. You never add anything to the list.

Comment: Because fibonacciList is NOT a FibonacciLinkedList. Even if you extended LinkedList, you would still be unable to access the display() method as it does not belong to the LinkedList class.

Comment: I suggest stepping through the code in your debugger to get a better understanding of what your program is actually doing/not doing.

Comment: 1) `LinkedList` in main should be `FibonacciLinkList`. 2) The method `sum` is never called. 3) The method `sum` never adds to the field `fibonacciList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned, `LinkedList` is not an instance of `FibonacciLinkedList`, and it does not possess the `display()` method. Attempting to invoke it on the `LinkedList` object will lead to failure to compile.

The `sum()` method is not invoked nor does it actually *do* anything. That is, it does not assign anything to the fibonacciList you have.

I would recommend that you [extend](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) the `LinkedList` class and generate the items on instantiation. Then, using the default toString() you can display to console. After all, the class is simply an *extension* of the LinkedList data structure to store Fibonacci numbers up to 20.

As you extend `LinkedList`, you inherit the [`AbstractCollection.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) method for which the "string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]")."

```
public class FibonacciLinkedList extends LinkedList<Integer> {
    public FibonacciLinkedList(int n){
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = a + b;
            this.add(c);
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FibonacciLinkedList list = new FibonacciLinkedList(20);
        list.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class FibonacciLinkList {
    private LinkedList<Integer> fibonacciList;

    public FibonacciLinkList() {
        this.fibonacciList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }

    public LinkedList<Integer> sum()
    {
        int n, a = 0, b = 0, c = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            fibonacciList.add(a);
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = a + b;
        }
        return fibonacciList;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(fibonacciList);  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FibonacciLinkList fibonacciList = new FibonacciLinkList();
        fibonacciList.sum();
        fibonacciList.display();
    }
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

There is several points that you need to take care :

- `sum()` is never called.
- the look in `sum()` does not change `fibonacciList`, it only uses local variables and does nothing else with it.
- `display()` is NOT a LinkedList function, so it will likely not work. And even if it were working, it will likely not display what you expect : you need to loop through the list and print each value.
- an other `fibonacciList` is created in the main function, so the display (if it was working) would show the content of this local list and not the global one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This has helped to understand the problem better.